# LLT polynomials and graded Specht modules

Tags: symmetric-functions, hecke-algebras

In the paper ``Ribbon Tableaux, Hall-Littlewood Functions, Quantum Affine Algebras And Unipotent Varieties'' Lascoux, Leclerc and Thibon define polynomials which quantise the Schur functions.  These $q$-analogues are now called LLT polynomials and are constructed using the highest weight theory for $U_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_n)$.

The Specht modules of symmetric groups and their Hecke algebras now admit graded character theory. For $q$ an $e$th root of unity,  one can define a polynomial ${\rm Deg}_q(S^\lambda)$ which is essentially defined using Fock space combinatorics for $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_e$.  This can be found in ``An Interpretation of the Lascoux–Leclerc–Thibon Algorithm and Graded Representation Theory" by Kleshchev and Nash.

My question is: are there any connections between these two polynomials?  The former is defined in terms of semistandard tableaux and the latter in terms of standard tableaux.  However, one could imagine a Schur functor type argument where one forgets certain information.  I'm also unsure as to whether one needs to specialise the LLT polynomials at a root of unity to get a direct link.